# WebStorm displaying an Error when the map object in Angular is accessed

Tags: angular, typescript, webstorm

In one of the services in my Angular project, I have called the `map()` function to get return data from GitHub API.

```
getUser(username: string) {
// RegEx used for String Manipulation
return this.http.get('https://api.github.com/users/'.concat(username))
 .map(res => res);}
```

However, when I try to call this method like this,

```
this.githubService.getUser('dasunpubudumal')
  .subscribe(user => {
    console.log(user.created_at); });
```

my WebStorm IDE displays a red line under *created_at* attribute. It says **TS2339 Property created_at does not exist on type 'Object'**.  However, when I run the code, it displays the *created_at* field of the JSON object which is returned from that endpoint.

Is there something which I am doing wrong? Is there any way that I could get rid of this error? I'm using *HttpClient* module for requesting from the endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. When implementing the method, I haven't declared the type of the object.

The function should be like this.

```
getUser(username: string) {
return this.http.get<User>('https://api.github.com/users/'.concat(username))
 .map(res => res);
```

}